# How do I login to ArgoCD running on KIND?

Tags: kubernetes, argocd, kind, gitops

The docs show `argocd login <ARGOCD_SERVER>` but they never say what ARGOCD_SERVER is. How can we login to ArgoCD on a kind cluster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ARGOCD_SERVER`: IP or domain to access in dashboard of ArgoCD.
Example:

```
argocd login 10.12.156.99:8443   
argocd login argocd.xxx.com
```